# issue while creating cloud identity account

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I was creating a cloud identity account using my domain name.I was at the step where I have to make a TXT entry in DNS, and my computer rebooted. now when I am trying, google says domain already in use. How can I overcome this issue ?

Comment: You don't have option to review the procedure, or to check again the key in DNS something like that. The special string to add should be displayed again.

Comment: I was able to access cloud identity using the user name password I had set. My provider added TXT code in dns server but till the verification is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to access cloud identity using the user name password I had set. issue resolved.